# When will chrome support WebGL on Linux?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

Any official statements on the matter? a release schedule?

Comment: It already does.

Comment: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1220892

Answer (score 3):

### It already does.

As [ohaal commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281124/when-will-chrome-support-webgl-on-linux#comment353320_281124), it's [already supported](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1220892).

> Supported operating systems
>
> - Windows Vista/ Windows 7/ Windows 8 (Windows 7 or later recommended)
> - Mac OS 10.6 or later
> - Linux
> - Chrome OS
>
> [...]
>
> Check to see if WebGL is enabled by by navigating to `chrome://gpu/` in your Chrome browser.

Try out some of the [demos](http://www.chromeexperiments.com/webgl) to see how it performs.

Answer (score 0):

You could visit [this page](http://www.webglreport.com/) with Chrome or with any browser and see a report of what is currently supported by the browser. The page checks your browser's WebGL capabilities.